# When to use PHP template engines

Tags: php, templates, template-engine

I am building a website in php with lot of pages and we are a team of 9 working on it. So just want to explore that when should we use PHP template engines and when we shouldn't. So I'm interested in pros and cons of using PHP Template engines so I can make a decision whether to use it in my case or not.

Answer (score 38):

## PHP is a template language.

In my experience so far with various template systems, the conclusion was pretty simple: *use none*.

Instead, write PHP as it should be written! Never do anything inside a .html besides `echo` and `for`/`foreach`. If you write the code based on a design pattern like MVC this becomes even more obvious: just `echo` and `foreach` inside and explain the frontends they should never mess with the code inside `<?php` and `?>`.

It worked for me ever since. It usually was harder for me to explain them Smarty than to explain to never mess with php.

Template systems also add weight to your server (sometimes is just a bit, sometimes you may feel it). It may seem over-optimization at first, but I prefer to keep it as simple as it can be.

**Note:**

Smarty, for example, is **HARDER** to spot in a .html file because the only Smarty syntax highlighter I know is a NetBeans plugin and it's pretty beta. PHP, on the other hand, has it syntax highlighted in any decent editor. Also easier for the frontends to spot and not mess with.

## Wrap up

### Cons (for using template system)

- Increases server load (lighter or heavier,  doesn't matter - you can see it)
- Induces bad practice (logic wrapped inside template language syntax)
- No syntax highlighting for template languages' syntax - harder to spot (for coder and frontend)
- Time spent learning it and teaching it to the frontends
- Harder to explain to the frontend team (I've taught basic PHP to frontends several times - while many more were already able to write their own 'beginner-level' PHP; I have **never** taught a frontend Smarty so they can do something other than `{$var}` )
- Makes you avoid the *REAL problem*: **logic and presentation separation**!
- Adds extra weight to your project

### Pros (for using template system)

- Extreme boredom (probably the only valid argument)

### Template system replacement

- Logic and presentation separation (I'd suggest **MVC** for this task and for the pros it provides for other fields of development: easier maintenance, abstract database and so on)
- Force yourself to write in the view only `echo` and iteration for echoing: `foreach` and `for` should accomplish 99% of the iteration needs; you can also use `while` and `do while`

Comment: I disagree with a lot of what you said. You seem a bit too biased I have to say. I've been using Twig for about a year now and I'd recommend it. Not saying you have to use it or it should be used in all cases but there definitely are benefits. Like automatic escaping to prevent XSS, etc. What you said about keeping the views simple, limiting the PHP usage, is good but surely that means a pro of templating engines has to be that there's only a limited set of commands/statements you can use.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using Twig/Smarty/xx but nothing done in them cannot be done in pure PHP and thus makes runtime/development a more efficient and cleaner process. Relying on your template engine for XSS prevention can only lead to trouble, this is where developers' knowledge is required. Let's not revisit magic_quotes...

Comment: I completely agree with your post. However, I think "only php echo and foreach" is not enough. What about boolean conditions? For example, you want to generate or not generate some html content, based on php data. How do you do that? You still have to put 'php if($bool) { generate html }' conditional in the template. Don't you?

Comment: 1 up for "Extreme boredom" in the "Pros" section ;-)

Comment: @Andrew `<?php if ($condition): ?>some html<?php else: ?>other html<?php end; ?>`

Comment: Or also: <?= $condition ? 'some html' : 'other html' ?>

Answer (score 11):

For me, when deciding if a separate template engine should be used or to just use PHP for the templating, it always boils down to this:

**When to use template engine**

When you must restrict (sandbox) the code that can be run in the templates.

---

**When not to use template engine**

All the other times.

---

Comment: This is exactly why Smarty has a part-time job here (the only reason). We need to run dynamic content from the database with security and some readability in mind. We use little tokens that clients copy/paste into a WYSIWYG that are parsed by Smarty, like {date} and {article_stub id="34"}. If anyone knows a better way to do it, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 6):

The PHP purists will tell you that PHP is itself a template engine. I consider myself a purist on this matter, and recommend just using PHP. It even has an alternate syntax for if and loop blocks that are pretty much designed for template-style readability.

Some people, however, still prefer using template engines, such as Smarty. There are a number of things to consider if you do choose that route:

**Who's going to be maintaining the template?** If the person maintaining the templates already knows PHP, there's no point in making them learn a new, pseudo-PHP template engine. If they don't know PHP, then it's still questionable, depending on their background, since most template engines just implement a syntax not unlike PHP tags (such as `<% %>`)

**How complicated will your templates get?** Some template engines are extremely restrictive in what you can do in the templates (forcing you to put everything in the controller, some almost to the point of uselessness or unnecessary hoop-jumping), while others are about as permissive as raw PHP (which many would argue defeats the purpose of a template engine).

**How much does efficiency and speed matter?** Template engines add overhead. Period. Converting the custom tags to PHP tags takes resources. How much they add and how much it matters depends on a number of factors (including the engine itself). If you need more speed from your site, then I'd vote the template engine as among the first to go.

As I said, I also recommend using PHP as your template "engine," but do be aware of some of the pitfalls. Mainly, it's really easy to add more logic than necessary into your templates. Make sure you have a rule to only include `echo`, `for/foreach`, and basic `if` blocks (such as `if is_admin()` and the like), and make sure to enforce it.

Comment: `Converting the custom tags to PHP tags takes resources` - Most template systems have (or should have) good caching features. Smarty compiles into pure php.

Comment: It still takes resources to compile them in the first place, and when the templates are updated.

Comment: Sure, but that's pretty negligible since it only happens once per edit. Finding and reading the cache however will add overhead, but not really converting the tags to php (creating the cache files).

Comment: Fair enough. Now here's a question - do all template engines cache the compiled templates? One would think they would, but then, in theory, theory and practice are the same...

Comment: @Wesley Murch , First: using cache makes it necessary to increase available RAM. Second: if we have to learn templates engine language to use them, why not we can spend this time to learn basics of PHP? It's not so hard to understand, how `echo`, `foreach` and `if` works. Not harder, than same constructions in template engines.

Comment: @OZ, please note the part I quoted in my original comment and read my second comment. I'm, not saying using a template system takes less resources, just noting that usually you don't parse the tags on the fly. I'm not advocating the use of template engines nor am I against it. As far as syntax goes, I agree php isn't hard to learn for basic usage, but it really is a lot cleaner to read template code for most folks. It depends, I know that when people who can't program see `<?php echo $user->name; ?>`, they know not to touch it, but if they saw {username} they might not know what it means.

Answer (score 3):

There is absolutely no reason to use a php template engine.
The seperation of logic and view is a obligation. This does NOT mean using a template engine.
With a template engine you have to learn things that have nothing to do with php or to do with anything else. Each person who have to modify the sources of smarty or an other template could be annoyed about that crap of anything useless and hindering mess.
PHP enpowers your templates an give you all possibilities in each way you use it.
With a dozen of advices PHP ist secure enough. Don't feel secure by using a template engine without knowledge of the tricks behind. Smarty can not secure public editable templates.

Look for Designpatterns. View Helper and MVC. Hold your code simple and well structured is meaning being smarter than smarty/any-template-engine ...

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using some method of good separation between your display logic and other data fetching maniuplation. Implementing MVC is a great way of doing this and most of the PHP frameworks provide an MVC framework.

This allows everyone to work on much cleaner code and allows the templates to remain simple so that those less technical (front-end designers for example) are able to go in and edit them.

Answer (score 2):

A template engine should be used when there is a great deal of presentation that is duplicated across multiple web pages and you have a desire to separate business and application programming and logic from presentation.

Benefits of this separation are:

1. tighter, more readable and error free application logic
2. alter presentation without altering core logic files
3. altering presentation dynamically at run time

While it is technically true that php is itself a template language it is more accurate to describe it as a web programming language with built in templating.  On the other hand it is also true that most template engines consume templates with programming directives built in.  This implies that a reasonable balance exists between too much template within php and too much programming within a template.  The better the balance the easier your coding and the more flexible and extensible your application will be.

Take for example php code that retrieves your last 10 blog posts and writes them out to a DIV tag on your blog when that code is invoked.  If that same code was duplicated to create an RSS feed you would have the same code in two places requiring the need to maintain it in multiple places when the logic changes.

If rather the exact same code is invoked under the control of a template engine then you have the same code writing to two different forms of output based on whether an RSS/XML or HTML template was provided.  If the template engine is written well the php code neither knows nor cares what type of template is provided to it.  The php could just as well be outputting HTML, XML, SQL, PDF, or text!

Having implemented many websites in Classic ASP and PHP over time I found that a good template engine saved me many long hours of programming and debugging and because there was no real template engine for Classic ASP I wrote KudzuASP to address the problem.  You can find the related project KudzuPHP on my website and it is free.  There is also a plugin for Wordpress based upon it.

Comment: `While it is technically true that php is itself a template language it is more accurate to describe it as a web programming language with built in templating.` I think it's somewhere in the middle. It originally came into existence to solve problems similar to the ones templating solves. It became robust later on.

Answer (score 1):

I would just use php for your template engine. No extra overload from having something like smarty. They just need to know basic php.  You can signify the template files with a `.phtml` file extension...Why would you want to use a templating engine?

---

Just to be clear, there should only be `echos` and `foreachs` inside the `.phtml` template files, no core code should be done inside of there.

Comment: 9 people working on a bunch of .phtml files with code and markup mixed together is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: How is that any different from 9 people working on a smarty template?  The real goal is to develop a set of standards for the templates. What should be in there, how the markup looks etc. Anything can be turned to trash if no standards are set and obeyed.

Comment: @David - 9 people writing code inside a .phtml file equals to 9 people who should learn logic and presentation separation. In a .phtml you `echo` and you iterate(`foreach`) in order to `echo`.

Comment: @David, I see where you were getting at. I guess my answer was a bit vague, gonna clear it up. What I meant was that you should just use PHP as the template engine and store the actual "Template" markup in `.phtml` files. I did not mean to include all the code etc inside the template markups.

Answer (score 1):

You should always use some mechanism for separating markup from code just like you shouldn't embed CSS in your HTML. There are too many options to give you a flat answer. There are template engines like smarty or fasttemplate, then there are frameworks with templating systems (like cake, code igniter, etc). You should evaluate them individually based on your needs

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Stamp Template Engine?

It still increases server load; however I think it fixes the other cons of template engines. Unlike Smarty and all the other template engines for PHP, StampTE is completely logic-less. You only mark regions with proper HTML comments (most designers and front-end engineers already have these markers just for readability). It relies on these markers to offer cut-and-paste functionality to back-end developers. Back-end PHP programmers can copy-and-paste these regions from the template (like paper models) and construct website and web application GUIs with it. Also, they have a very friendly API themselves. For instance to cut a region like:

```
   <!-- cut:siteMenu -->
       <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>...</li>
          </ul>
       </nav>
   <!-- /cut:siteMenu -->
```

They can use object oriented notation:

```
$template->getSiteMenu()->setLink( ... ); etc..
```

I think this is really cool.

http://www.stampte.com

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, **separation** and **reuse** are the keywords here.

The best way to develop and to segment the work load within a team, is when the Web Designer (integrator/html-ist and so on) has no chance of breaking down the programming part (database, files, sessions, syntax errors and so on).

I recommend using the [FigDice Template Engine](http://www.figdice.org/), which operates a very neat separation between the Logics (program, database, files, algorithms, etc.) and the Presentation (the views and the information they present) in total security.

FigDice supports of course macros (reusable parts of a file), inclusion, iterations, and many more features, and also provides an exclusive approach to the Presentation/Logics separation, with the inversion of control of the data-providers (the Views pull the information they need to display, rather than letting the controllers push the data into the templates, as is usually the case with virtually every template engine).
This makes it possible to the HTML Designer to really decide what he wants to present and when and how, without any risk of breaking down the code.

I would be happy to get feedback and comments.
Thanks