# Forwarding tags like {blabla} to php functions

Tags: php, html, web, tags

I saw this in most of CMS and forum templates. How can I make HTML tags like `{blabla}` and how can I forward them to PHP functions?

Comment: `forward them to php functions?` what do you mean? can you be bit more specfic?

Comment: preg replace, str replace, i guess... however, this will slow down application, and it is not actually needed, imho. :) some say - php is templating language it self. :) http://stackoverflow.com/a/5888214/2045185

Comment: try using some templating scripts [smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) uses similar tags. and another link about comparisons http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/19-promising-php-template-engines/

Comment: Your question appears to be Too Broad  / Unattempted / Unclear.  Using a bounty should not be leveraged to use this community as a free code writing service.  I feel this question should be improved or closed when the bounty is over.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These are called templating systems and the style of these *"tags"* depends on the templating system you're using.

A basic example in PHP would be something like this:

**page.tpl:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Basic templating system</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Welcome to our website, {{name}} !</h2>
    <p>Please confirm your account. We've sent an email to: {{email}}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.php:**

```
<?php
// Get the template's content
$template = file_get_contents("page.tpl");

// The data needed in the template
$data = array(
    'name' => 'John',
    'email' => 'john@smith.com',
);

// The template's tags pattern
$pattern = '{{%s}}';

// Preparing the $map array used to replace the template's tags with data values
$map = array();
foreach($data as $var => $value)
{
    $map[sprintf($pattern, $var)] = $value;
}

// Replace the tags with data values
$output = strtr($template, $map);

// Output the template with replaced tags
echo $output;

?>
```

I recommend that you check out already existing templating engines such as: [Mustache](http://mustache.github.io/), [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) or [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) and many others

Hope this helps :) !

Comment: Twig is a very nice templating engine (based on Jinja2 from python)