# Best practice for outputting larger amounts of dynamic HTML from PHP

Tags: php, html

What is the best practice for exporting larger amounts of HTML from a database in PHP? I am building a very simple, dynamic CMS and have intentions of loading the input type, id, etc from the MySQL database.

My question is using just an echo like the sample code provided below the absolute best method for displaying the HTML assuming I have collected the information from the database?

```
for ($x = 0; $x < 3; $x++)
    {
        echo '
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
              </div>
        ';
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888089/when-to-use-php-template-engines

Comment: Personally if I have to output a lot of HTML, I avoid using `echo` or `print` as it is just plain ugly and hard to read when you combine them with curly braces and semicolons. Instead, I use PHP's [alternative syntax for control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) mixed with the short echo tag `<?= ?>`.

Comment: By default php web server have a limit of 2MB of data transfer with 30s timeout, so if you have a large amount of data in echo then your script will be unresponsive and to avoid that it is better to use a different technique like ajax etc for fetching data from DB. Your technique is good only for small amount of data.

Comment: Suspect this may be closed as either *too broad* or *primarily opinion based* ... you're not asking for a solution to a problem with a specific piece of code - more opinions on design patterns.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably be asking some hard questions around sanitization and html encoding, this could be opening yourself up to XSS

Are you in full control of the HTML or can the user enter it?

Can you use markdown or some other language to html to help prevent attackers running malicious css/js?

If not you may need something heavy handed like [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) which will likely suck up performance

In terms of output I'd recommend requiring a separate PHP file and using it as a "template" file since PHP is a templating language.

Other developers will probably chime in and recommend a made up language (DSL) to render what will essentially become PHP at some stage, those languages should offer htmlspecialchars on variables by default and caching in exchange for their DSL

This could be preferable if you're not really sure what you're doing

If you are outputting predefined blocks of things what you could do is store those blocks in your database as function names, then on output call those functions dynamically via db to render the blocks